# How do I access 'document' within a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

FYI I'm an absolute beginner at JavaScript and I've tried googling solutions but I don't even know what I don't know so that led me here.

From what I understand the addEventListener is supposed to be moving the frame div following the mouse. However my problem is that document.addEventListener comes up with a parsing error which I'm not completely sure what it means. This seems to only happen whenever I type document by itself and not assign it to a var like with the var frame = document.getElementById line.

```
class StickyFrame extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="frame" >
        <StickyNote />
      </div>
    );
  }
  frame = document.getElementById('frame');
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', 
  function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX;
    var y = e.clientY;
    frame.style.left = x + "px";
    frame.style.top = y + "px";
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: You can't just put code in the class body, it should go in the constructor instead. Though there are better React-specific solutions to this problem (see answers below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. Querying the DOM for elements is anti-pattern in React, use a React ref to gain access to underlying DOMNodes.
2. Event listeners should be be added and removed via component lifecycle methods.

Code

```
class StickyFrame extends React.Component{
  frameRef = React.createRef();

  handler(e) {
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY;
    frame.current?.style.left = x + "px";
    frame.current?.style.top = y + "px";
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handler);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="frame" ref={this.frameRef} >
        <StickyNote />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in React you can use event handler, and for 'mousemove' event you can use `onMouseMove` event. see the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events.

or if you want to access DOM Node, you can utilize `Refs`. like this:

```js
class StickyFrame extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    this.frame = this.frameValue.bind(this);
  }


  frameValue() {
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    this.myRef.current;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="frame" ref={this.myRef} >
        <StickyNote />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

for complete explanation, you can see the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html